# Updating Semantic Mediawiki using Composer fails for unknown reason. What can I do to make it work?

Tags: php, mediawiki-extension

I am pretty new in this field but I managed to install and run Mediawiki (1.31.0) and Semantic MediaWiki (2.5.6) with an external provider. 
Now I am trying to upgrade to Semantic Mediawiki 3.0 following the installation guide (i.e. using composer). The process seems to work but half (?) way updating dependencies the process is stopped, ending with the message "Killed". How can I prevent this failure?

This is the full text on my PuTTy screen:

```
xlane.nl@one.com/www/betawiki$ php composer.phar update --no-dev -vvv
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Executing command (/customers/4/1/9/xlane.nl/httpd.www/betawiki): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/customers/4/1/9/xlane.nl/httpd.www/betawiki): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (/customers/4/1/9/xlane.nl/httpd.www/betawiki): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD
Executing command (/customers/4/1/9/xlane.nl/httpd.www/betawiki): hg branch
Executing command (/customers/4/1/9/xlane.nl/httpd.www/betawiki): fossil branch list
Executing command (/customers/4/1/9/xlane.nl/httpd.www/betawiki): fossil tag list
Executing command (/customers/4/1/9/xlane.nl/httpd.www/betawiki): svn info --xml
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/xlane.nl/.composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading /customers/4/1/9/xlane.nl/httpd.www/betawiki/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin Wikimedia\Composer\MergePlugin
  [merge-plugin] Loading composer.local.json...
  [merge-plugin] Merging mediawiki/semantic-media-wiki
Running 1.8.3 (2019-01-30 08:31:33) with PHP 7.2.14 on Linux / 4.4.134+20180824.0648.fc9acc4c.xenial
  [merge-plugin] Already merged composer.local.json completely
> pre-update-cmd: ComposerHookHandler::onPreUpdate
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /home/xlane.nl/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies
Reading /home/xlane.nl/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /home/xlane.nl/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading /home/xlane.nl/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading /home/xlane.nl/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading /home/xlane.nl/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Reading /home/xlane.nl/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018.json from cache
Reading /home/xlane.nl/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018-04.json from cache
Reading /home/xlane.nl/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018-07.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2018-10%244480dd3a8a06f875d02875a3784b38258f3cd53a96e69f3c3a6c57cbf048a3e3.json
Killed
```

Answer (score 0):

"Killed" means something reached out and terminated your process - and it's not a code problem like a segfault.

I bet what happened is that Composer consumed too much memory on your system, and the Linux OOM (out of memory) killer terminated Composer out of necessity to ensure your system would stay running.

To confirm this, you need to look at your system logs. You didn't specify what flavor of Linux you're running, but one of the following should work:

- `journalctl`
- `dmesg`
- `less /var/log/syslog`
- `less /var/log/messages`

Any references to OOM around the time you were running Composer confirms this diagnosis - you need to give your machine more RAM.

Another way to verify would be to open another connection to your machine, start composer, and keep one eye on the output of `top` or `free` as it runs.